# How to fix a time series with missing dates across multiple observations?

Tags: r, time-series, data-cleaning

Let us consider the following time series with numbered days :

```
test=data.table( day=sample(1:9, 15, TRUE), name=sort(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 5)), value=sample(1:3, 15, TRUE) )
test[test[, !duplicated(day), by=name][,V1]][order(name, -day)]
    day name value
 1:   7    a     3
 2:   4    a     2
 3:   2    a     2
 4:   1    a     2
 5:   9    b     1
 6:   8    b     3
 7:   6    b     3
 8:   5    b     2
 9:   3    b     3
10:   7    c     1
11:   6    c     1
12:   4    c     1
13:   3    c     3
14:   1    c     2
```

As you can see we made some measurments on three objects `a, b and c` during 9 days. We would like to perform a day to day `value` comparison between the three objects, unfortunately some dates are randomly missing and this causes a problem to run an algorithm that would otherwise be straightforward.

I would like to inject rows into this datatable so all objects have the same days. Injected rows would default the `value` to `0`

All days available across all objects are listed with :

```
> sort(unique(test[,day]) )
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

So for instance the object `a` is missing days : `3, 5, 6, 8, 9`

After the row injection the datatable for `a` would look like :

```
test[name=="a"]
   day name value
1:   1    a     2
2:   2    a     1
3:   3    a     0
4:   4    a     3
5:   5    a     0
6:   6    a     0
7:   7    a     3
8:   8    a     0
9:   9    a     0
```

Any idea on how to tackle this problem ? Maybe some libraries such as `lubridate` already know how to do that.

Comment: You need to use `set.seed(1)` or similar in the first line so that your example is reproducible since you are using `sample()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data that you posted, which I copied and put into a `data.table`, you can do this using:

```
library(data.table)
## create a table with all days and names
all.dates <- setDT(expand.grid(day=sort(unique(test[,day])),name=sort(unique(test[,name]))))
## perform a left-outer-join of all.dates with test
setkey(all.dates)
setkey(test,day,name)
test <- test[all.dates]
## set those NA's to zero
test[is.na(test)] <- 0
##   day name value
##1    1    a     2
##2    1    b     0
##3    1    c     2
##4    2    a     2
##5    2    b     0
##6    2    c     0
##7    3    a     0
##8    3    b     3
##9    3    c     3
##10   4    a     2
##11   4    b     0
##12   4    c     1
##13   5    a     0
##14   5    b     2
##15   5    c     0
##16   6    a     0
##17   6    b     3
##18   6    c     1
##19   7    a     3
##20   7    b     0
##21   7    c     1
##22   8    a     0
##23   8    b     3
##24   8    c     0
##25   9    a     0
##26   9    b     1
##27   9    c     0
```

**Data:**

```
test <- structure(list(day = c(7L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 1L), name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L)), .Names = c("day", "name", "value"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102006778>)
 ##    day name value
 ## 1:   7    a     3
 ## 2:   4    a     2
 ## 3:   2    a     2
 ## 4:   1    a     2
 ## 5:   9    b     1
 ## 6:   8    b     3
 ## 7:   6    b     3
 ## 8:   5    b     2
 ## 9:   3    b     3
 ##10:   7    c     1
 ##11:   6    c     1
 ##12:   4    c     1
 ##13:   3    c     3
 ##14:   1    c     2
```

Comment: Who is the genius who designed datatables ?

Answer (score 1):

In the `tidyverse`, one of the packages (`tidyr`) has a wrapper over `expand.grid` and `left.join`.

```
library(tidyverse)
test$day <- factor(test$day, levels = 1:9)
test$name = factor(test$name, levels = c("a", "b", "c"))
test %>% 
    complete(day, name, fill = list(value = 0))
#> # A tibble: 32 Ã— 3
#>       day   name value
#>    <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
#> 1       1      a     0
#> 2       1      b     0
#> 3       1      c     0
#> 4       2      a     0
#> 5       2      b     0
#> 6       2      c     1
#> 7       3      a     1
#> 8       3      b     0
#> 9       3      c     0
#> 10      4      a     3
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

You can also do it with `expand.grid` and a left join.

```
possibilities = expand.grid(levels(test$day), unique(test$name))

possibilities %>%
    left_join(test, by = c("Var1" = "day", "Var2" = "name")) %>%
    mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), 0, value))
#>    Var1 Var2 value
#> 1     1    a     0
#> 2     2    a     0
#> 3     3    a     1
#> 4     4    a     3
#> 5     5    a     1
```